# Add post to specified category (from title) if already existing

Tags: php, wordpress

I hired someone to develop a plugin that would create a wordpress post from a title. Unfortunately, I realized after 1 month that there is a bug in it, and this coder is asking me money to correct it. I hope you can help me.

If the title doesn't exist, it creates a post in a new category (based on the title).
If the title has already been posted, it will add the post to the existing category. and that's where the code bug. It doesn't add any category. It goes through, but no category at all. not even "uncategorized"

```
if($_GET['page'] == "wp_posts" && isset($_GET['add']))
    {

      $date= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $table =  $wpdb->prefix .'terms';
         $c="select * from $table where name='$_GET[category]'";
        $cat=$wpdb->get_results($c);
         echo $cs=sizeof($cat);         
         if($cs >=1)
         {
            foreach ($cat as $his )                             
                {
                    print_r($his);  
                    $cat_id=$his->term_id;
                }
         }
         else
         {
             $cat_id = wp_create_category($_GET['category']);                   
         }
         echo 'cat_idd'.$cat_id;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: _and that's where the code bug_ : what does it do ? a wrong record at the wrong place, an error message... ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. It doesn't add any category. It goes through, but no category at all. not even "uncategorized"

Comment: Missing some code here, so it's not easy to tell where the issue is.  For example in your query _$c="select * from $table where name='$_GET[category]'";_ where do you take $_GET[category] from ?  You could try to print the $c variable to see what is the final sql query made of... this could probably help to investigate…

Comment: The $_GET[category] is the title. It wasnt well coded I must admit.
I fixed it by mistake. took off all the echo and print and it works well now.